# Ввод параметра для строк и столбцов с клавиатуры, а заполнение матрицы случайным образом

Tags: массивы, pascal

Здравствуйте!

Нужно сделать так, чтобы параметры для строк и столбцов вводились с клавиатуры, а сама матрица заполнялась случайным образом. При чем реализация ввода матрицы должна быть в процедуре. А вывод матрицы на экран в другой процедуре.

Делаю пока что для ввода матрицы. Но не совсем получается.

> Ошибка: "Error 20: Variable identifier expected".

И указывает на переменную `a` в процедуре.
Так понимаю, что и для переменной `b` будет та же ситуация.

Думаю, что `const` нужно убрать, потому что это все таки константы, а мне нужно переменное значение. Но тогда выходит ошибка в строке

```
type mass = array [1..a,1..b] of integer;
```

Потому что `a` и `b` не определены.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать. Как правильно написать?

Буду ОЧЕНЬ благодарна, если напишите пример:)

Вот, что получилось у меня.

```
const a=10;
      b=10;

type mass = array [1..a,1..b] of integer;

var matr : mass;

procedure zapolnenie_matricij;
   begin
      var i,j:integer;

      writeln('Введите параметр для строк: ');
      readln(a);

      writeln('Введите параметр для столбцов: ');
      readln(b);

      randomize;
      for i:=1 to a do
      begin
         for j:=1 to b do
            begin
               matr[i,j]=random(15);
            end;
      end;

   end;
```

Если пробую прописать `a` и `b` как переменные в процедуре, то появляется ошибка "Error 113: Error in statement".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы Вашу программу написал так:

```
 Const { здесь ограничимся максимально возможными числами строк и столбцов }
      a0=20;
      b0=20;

    Var
      Matr: Array[1..a0, 1..b0] Of Integer;
      a, b: integer; { а здесь зададим переменные }

    procedure zapolnenie_matricij;
    var
      i, j: integer;
    begin
(* тут проверяем попадает ли введённое число а заданную границу *)
      Repeat
        write('a = ');
        readln(a);
      Until (a In [2..a0]);

      Repeat
        write('b = ');
        readln(b);
      Until (b In [2..b0]);

      randomize; 
(* советую приучаться не писать "лишние" программные скобки begin...end *)
      for i:=1 to a do
        for j:=1 to b do
          matr[i,j]:=random(15);
    end;

    Procedure MatrixScreenOut;
    var
      i, j: integer;
    Begin
      for i:=1 to a do
        begin
          for j:=1 to b do
            Write(matr[i,j]:3);
          WriteLn;
        end;
    End;

    begin
      zapolnenie_matricij;
      MatrixScreenOut;

      WriteLn('Davi na ENTER!!!');
      ReadLn;
    end.
```

А если все делать в одной процедуре, то можно обойтись и одним циклом (со вложенным):

```
 for i:=1 to a do
    begin
      for j:=1 to b do
        begin
          matr[i,j]:=random(15);
          Write(matr[i,j]:3);
        end;
      WriteLn;
    end;
```

В этом случае не придётся заполнять, а потом выводить матрицу отдельно.

Answer (score 2):

В паскале нельзя инициализировать переменные в разделе `var`. Но это реализуется с помощью типизированных констант, которые на самом деле не константы:

```
const a : integer = 10;
      b : integer = 10;
```

Получим две переменные `a` и `b`, несмотря на `const`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, получилось сделать так, как нужно. Правда все в одной процедуре, но главное работает:)

Answer (score 0):

Надо заменить `const` на `var`:

```
var a,b:integer;
```

Comment: Нет, тогда появляется другая ошибка. "Error 133: Cannot evaluate this expression".

Answer (score 0):

Ура! Сделала сама нужную процедуру!:)
В двух процедурах не получилось.
Но получилось в одной.
И, главное, работает правильно!

Вот итог моих трудов:)

```
        program zadanie;

    uses crt;

    const a = 10; {dlya zadaniya strok matricij}
          b = 10; {dlya zadaniya stolbcov matricij}

    type  mass = array [1..a, 1..b] of integer;

    var   matr : mass; {dlya matricij}
          m    : integer; {znachenie dlya sravneniya}
          i,j:integer;

    {*********************************************************************}

    procedure matrica_na_ekrane; {procedyra dlya vivoda matricij na ekran}

    var i,j:integer;
        a,b:integer;

    begin
       writeln('Vvedite a: ');
       readln(a);

       writeln('Vvedite b: ');
       readln(b);

       randomize;
       for i:=1 to a do
       begin
          for j:=1 to b do
             begin
                matr[i,j]:=random(10);
             end;
       end;

       for i:=1 to a do
       begin
          for j:=1 to b do
             begin
                write(matr[i,j]:5);
             end;
          writeln;writeln;
       end;

    end;

    {*********************************************************************}

    BEGIN
   clrscr;

   matrica_na_ekrane;

   readln;
END.
```

Comment: Нужно учитывать, что если пользователь введёт a или b > 10, то произойдет выход за пределы первоначального массива с размерами 10x10 (после изменения а или b размеры самого массива не изменяются автоматически). Нужно или делать начальные а и b побольше (100 и 100 например), или выделять память динамически (см. [здесь](http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=51192) например), или переходить на Delphi и использовать динамические массивы